# Search for text within a certain scope in a file? (Sublime)

Tags: search, scope, editor, sublimetext

I know that sublime text categorizes the source code into different scopes. Especially used for syntax highlighting. 
(You can display the current scope with Ctrl+Alt+Shift P or diverse plugins)

But can you also search for/within one scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no functionality built in to ST2 or ST3 that allows searches to be confined to a particular scope. If you know Python, a plugin shouldn't be too hard to write using the [functions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) `sublime.View.find()` and `sublime.View.find_all()`, filtering the results through `sublime.View.scope_name()`, although you'd need to collapse the `Region` returned by `find()` to a single point for passing to `scope_name()`.

If you're not the plugin-writing type, you might want to check out the [`ScopeHunter`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeHunter) and/or [`ScopeAlways`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ScopeAlways) plugins, available through [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). I bind the ScopeHunter functionality to a key combination that pops up a panel with the current scope:

```json
[
    // ScopeHunter
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "get_selection_scope" }
]
```

A slightly less keyboard-intensive method would be to use ScopeAlways, which displays the current scope in the status bar:

[image: ScopeAlways]

This way you can move through your Find results and immediately see what scope(s) they belong to. To set it up, once you've installed the plugin from Package Control, open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> ScopeAlways -> Settings - User` and add the following to have it start when Sublime starts:

```json
{
    "start_on": true
}
```

Save the file, restart Sublime, and enjoy all the scope goodness.